# Strange result or am I wrong?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string `[row element="div"]This is a row[/row]` and I like to extract fromt this string the `div` property and the string `This is a row` by using JavaScript and Regex.

The way I am trying to perform this action is the following:

```
var string = '[row element="div"]This is a row[/row]';
var $d     = string.match(/\[row element="([^"]+)"\](.*?)\[\/row\]/g);

console.log($d);
```

and the result is:

```
[row element="div"]This is a row[/row]
```

So, the question is, am I doing it wrong, or the code behaves strange ?

If this is wrong, how can I extract that parts needed from the `string` variable ?

Comment: removing the `/g` from the regex it outputs `["[row element="div"]This is a row[/row]", "div", "This is a row", index: 0, input: "[row element="div"]This is a row[/row]"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `/g` and `.match` are not compatible with subpatterns.

Instead, try the other way around:

```
var regex = /......../g;
var $d = regex.exec(string);

console.log($d);
```

The result should be an array, containing the entire match at index 0, the first subpattern as 1, and the second at 2.

You can call `.exec` repeatedly to see if there are any more `[row element="foo"]bar[/row]` patterns matching. `.exec` will return `null` if there are no more matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var $d = string.match(/\[row element="(?:[^"]+)"\](.*?)\[\/row\]/)[1];
//=> "This is a row"
```